# Can you use Glyph of Warding to prepare for a difficult fight and avoid total party kill?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, total-party-kill

I was wondering if in the past our party could have prepared better to fight a potentially deadly foe. We had time to prepare for this and could have used a *Glyph of Warding* or two, but we didn't. We had a day to prepare for the fight as I recall. The short version of what happened is that we had a TPK (total party kill) when facing a dragon. Some were lost outright and a couple of us were restored to life from a couple of charred bones by a "court of healers" - which was quite magnanimous of our DM really.

I've been mulling this over recently while reading other questions and wondered about how we could have prepared better.

**My question is whether we could have used *Glyph of Warding* to prevent the TPK.**

Could we have set up a spell like *Healing Word* (range of 60 ft.) to be triggered when a particular PC's hit points went down to 0 hit points, died? Or, a spell like *Aura of Life* (range of self) with the *Glyph of Warding* to be triggered when the first PC was killed?
(PHB, pp. 216, 250, 267)

I could see how both of these spells in a *Glyph of Warding* would have saved our bacon but want to check whether this would have been possible.

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158134/what-are-the-targeting-range-limitations-of-glyph-of-warding

Comment: Are you just asking if *glyph* works with healing spells?

Comment: @Kirt Please don’t write answers in comments.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I believe I was trying to get OP to clarify their question so that informed answers are possible.  I don't see asking where the fight takes place as providing an answer to the question of whether a glyph can be used to avoid a TPK.

Comment: Hi Thomas, it is about using the Glyph of Warding and a spell that can potentially heal a target or in an area, so as to trigger when the PC(s) hit 0 HP. I didn't add the whole background because it didn't seem necessary. I'm not asking what to do next or how to defeat the dragon. Not sure Vlaz's sarcasm was necessary but a "Kill Dragon With No Save" spell would be handy, yes. ;)

Comment: Asking "Can healing spells be stored in a Glyph of Warding" is a fundamentally different question to "Can Glyph of Warding prevent a total party kill" which in turn is similar but not exactly the same question as "Can Glyph of Warding prevent a total party kill when fighting a dragon".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, you could have used *glyph of warding* this way

Spells that can be stored into a glyph of warding must fullfill these conditions:

> You can store a **prepared spell of 3rd level or lower** in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph. The spell **must target a single creature or an area**.

That includes [spells that target self](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115540/can-a-spell-with-a-target-of-self-be-stored-in-glyph-of-warding). *Aura of life* is 4th level, so it will not work unless you upcast the *glyph* to 4th or higher level. *Healing word* will work without a hitch, as it is a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower that targets a creature. The pre-errata version of glyph talked about harmful effects, but this has been removed [in errata](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/135998/75095), so now beneficial effects can be stored too.

What is more difficult to decide is the circumstances that trigger the *glyph*. While the spell has quite a bit of language about it, much [remains unclear](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148364/what-is-the-limit-to-a-glyph-of-wardings-trigger) and needs the DM. For example, [is there a range limit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141537/is-there-a-limit-on-the-detection-range-of-glyph-of-wardings-trigger)? Is the glyph [omniscient](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164260/does-a-glyph-of-warding-have-its-own-agency-or-a-limited-omniscience-in-the-game)? Can it trigger on your [own death](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100711/can-your-own-death-be-a-trigger-for-glyph-of-warding)? Can it see [the future](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/179952/how-to-determine-the-sex-of-an-unborn-baby/179973#179973)? And so on. But I think an in-character visible event, such as a character falling unconscious from damage should not be a problem.

So yes, you probably could have changed the odds a bit more in your favor, by preparing the area where you stood your ground with such *glyphs*.